# Joined Table Inheritance Mapping vs Composition in Object Relational Databases

Tags: python, web-applications, orm, sqlalchemy

I've recently started using SQLAlchemy without any prior knowledge of SQL. A problem I've been facing is how to introduce polymorphic behavior. As an example, consider Reddit-like web application; we have a model for `Article` and one for `Comment` and both can be voted on:

```
class Article(Base):
    id       = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    data     = Column(Text)
    comments = relationship('Comment')
    #... more article-related attributes
    votes      = relationship('Vote')
    vote_ups   = Column(Integer, default = 0)
    vote_downs = Column(Integer, default = 0) 

class Comment(Base):
    id   = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    data = Column(Text)
    #... more comment-related attributes
    votes      = relationship('Vote')
    vote_ups   = Column(Integer, default = 0)
    vote_downs = Column(Integer, default = 0)
```

I would like to detach the voting attributes, which are common to both models, so that I don't have to repeat code for each model that can be voted on.

My first thought was to create a new `VotesComponent` model, containing the attributes as so,

```
class VotesComponent(Base):
    votes      = relationship('Vote')
    vote_ups   = Column(Integer)
    vote_downs = Column(Integer)
```

and establishing a many to one relation ship with the `Comment` and `Article` models.

Digging through the SQLAlchemy documentation, I later found out something similar can be achieved by using [joined table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance). At first this seems really convenient, since an additional level of indirection is avoided (i.e. one can refer to comment.votes instead of comment.votes_component.votes), but one big drawback I see with my limited understanding, is that multiple inheritance is not supported, whereas with the earlier method, one is free to add as many 'Components' to a model.

So, my question is, what are the benefits of using inheritance mapping over composition, and when is either preferable and why? In this case, which of the two (or perhaps different) methods would you recommend?

**EDIT**: I should mention that I want to be able to query the "Vote" part of the models separately, so that I can polymorphically handle voting.

Comment: The title is misleading; "Object Relational Databases" should be "Object Relational Mapper". SQLAlchemy can use both object and non-object relational database systems.

Comment: I edited the title, I hope it's less misleading. Please understand that my knowledge on databases is quite limited, hence the misleading title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, but borderline off-topic here because questions that invite opinion-based answers are frowned upon at stackoverflow. That said, here is my personal take (I really want to avoid starting a flamewar).

> So, my question is, what are the benefits of using inheritance mapping over composition, and when is either preferable and why?

In most OO languages inheritance is linked to "is-a" questions, while composition is linked to "has-a" questions. Composition in Python is often implemented through multiple inheritance, so the "composition versus inheritance" question is a bit odd. The language promotes a [Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python) style, so "has-a" questions are considered more idiomatic.

When we talk about ORMs, there are other implications: how is inheritance implemented under the hood? Some implementations will spread the object data over multiple tables and perform SQL JOINs, other will use single tables and perform SQL UNIONs. IMHO this is not something you should waste energy thinking about. First reason is that it is transparent for you, this is the whole point when using an ORM. Second, you lack the knowledge to judge which one is better for your specific use case (you would have to dive into SQL and the specific implementation details of the several RDBMs out there to understand the performance implications involved).

My advice is to implement it using your prefered programming style, trust the choices of the ORM implementation and let the performance concerns to the DBA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping my question had a clear answer, not an opinion-based one. As I said in my question, I would prefer going with the OO approach, but SQLAlchemy's inheritance mapping is limited to single inheritance. Could you elaborate on this limitation?

Comment: This means you can't inherit from more than one parent simultaneously, which makes sense - if you want to inherit from multiple classes you are using composition. Please read about "[Mixins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#mixin-and-custom-base-classes)", I guess it is the best choice for your use case.